# how to align center a bitmap inside a canvas in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

i have a bitmap on canvas.i need to align bitmap to centre of canvas(centre of the image should be in centre of canvas.in my requirement,there should not give fixed points to align bitmap).while portrait view how to scale canvas and image appropriate to resolution?

```
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Bitmap imgtable = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.table_01);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    canvas.drawBitmap(imgtable, 10, 10, null);

    }
```

Comment: Also noteworthy is the solution proposed  [in this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143321/how-to-align-center-a-bitmap)

Comment: i was facing the same issue, this answer helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/8143775/9934266

Answer (score 56, accepted):

While i do not know the specific methods of getting the canvas width and bitmap width in Android, to place an bitmap at the center usually goes something like this.

```
centreX = (canvasWidth  - bitmapWidth) /2

centreY = (canvasHeight - bitmapHeight) /2
```

Then place your image at centreX,centreY

Comment: but in my case,there is a problem.That is,my image is fit in landscape mode.but in portrate mode there the image overflow the screen.

Comment: @KIRANKJ Have you solved the problem? I am facing the same problem

Comment: When you rotate the device you probably need to recalculate so width becomes height and height become width.