# How to align center a bitmap?

Tags: android

i want my bitmap in the center of my screen..i m trying it that way but its not working...

```
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.compass);

            int w = canvas.getWidth();
            int h = canvas.getHeight();

            int bw=myBitmap.getWidth();
            int bh=myBitmap.getHeight();

            int cx = w / 2;
            int cy = h / 2;

            Display d = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            int x = d.getWidth();
            int y = d.getHeight();
            int dx = x / 2;
            int dw = y /2;
            canvas.translate(cx, cy);    
            if (mValues != null) {
                canvas.rotate(-mValues[0]);
            }  

            int centreX = (x  - bw) /2;

                int centreY = (cy - bh) /2;  
            //canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, centreX,centreY, null);
```

Comment: What is the end result with this code? (How is the image aligned)

Comment: In which class & function do you use this code? (Activity/View, onDraw...)

Comment: i use it in protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas). the result is the top/left of my image in the 0,0

Comment: Does your view occupy the whole screen area? (i.e. you have one view as a drawing surface)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's the code you need in your view:

```java
private int mWidth;
private int mHeight;
private float mAngle;

@Override protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    mWidth = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    mHeight = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    setMeasuredDimension(mWidth, mHeight);
}

@Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.compass);

    // Here's the magic. Whatever way you do it, the logic is:
    // space available - bitmap size and divide the result by two.
    // There must be an equal amount of pixels on both sides of the image.
    // Therefore whatever space is left after displaying the image, half goes to
    // left/up and half to right/down. The available space you get by subtracting the
    // image's width/height from the screen dimensions. Good luck.

    int cx = (mWidth - myBitmap.getWidth()) >> 1; // same as (...) / 2
    int cy = (mHeight - myBitmap.getHeight()) >> 1;

    if (mAngle > 0) {
        canvas.rotate(mAngle, mWidth >> 1, mHeight >> 1);
    }

    canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, cx, cy, null);
}
```

Screenshot just for fun: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1Bdp.jpg
(Diagonal lines not part of the code posted here)

EDIT: Added NickT's solution.
EDIT 2: Changed mvalues[0] to mAngle and made it conditional. Changed divide by 2 operations to bitshifts. Remove rotation code if you don't need it.

Comment: This should work OK, but the pivot point for the rotate will need changing to canvas.rotate(-mValues[0], mWidth/2, mHeight/2), otherwise it will pivot on a corner, not the centre

Comment: thanks!!this is working fine!one last answer please.there is no problem i m not using canvas.translate(cx, cy);    
            if (mValues != null) {
                canvas.rotate(-mValues[0]);
            }

Comment: Thanks @NickT for the rotation. Edited into the answer.

Comment: One improvement. Always try to use shift operators when dealing with multiplication or division with 2 (or multiples of 2), specially in onDraw(). Here e.g. replace "mWidth/2" with "mWidth >> 1"

Comment: what is `-mValues[0]` ?

Comment: hi please tell me what is -mvalues[0]?

Comment: Changed -mvalues[0] to mAngle. NickT took the rotation code from the question, which has that unexplained value. You can remove it if rotation not needed.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this :

```
        int width = containerBitmap.getWidth();
        int height = containerBitmap.getHeight();
        float centerX = (width  - centeredBitmap.getWidth()) * 0.5f;
        float centerY = (height- centeredBitmap.getHeight()) * 0.5f;
```

You can use it to draw a bitmap at the center of another bitmap.