# How to center align center a Bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, live, wallpaper

I am trying to align center a Bitmap, but I keep failing to do so. I am making a live wallpaper for Android that keeps looping the image. I have simple background and an animation image that overlaps the background.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

/*
 * This animated wallpaper draws a rotating wireframe cube.
 */
public class CubeWallpaper1 extends WallpaperService {



    public static final String SHARED_PREFS_NAME="cube1_settings";
    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    private static boolean Reverse= false;
    private static boolean screenfit = false;
    private static String slow;
    private static String fast;
    private static String medium;
    private static String framerate;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public Engine onCreateEngine() {
        return new CubeEngine();
    }

    class CubeEngine extends Engine implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

        private final Paint mPaint = new Paint();
        private float mOffset;
        private float mTouchX = -1;
        private float mTouchY = -1;
        private long mStartTime;
        private float mCenterX;
        private float mCenterY;
        private float bottom;
        private int i=1;
        private float  screenwidth;
        private float halfscreenwidth;
        private float screenheight;
        private float  screenhalfheight;
        private boolean plus = false;
        private final Runnable mDrawCube = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                drawFrame();
            }
        };
        private boolean mVisible;
        private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
        CubeEngine() {
            final Paint paint = mPaint;
            paint.setColor(0xffffffff);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
            paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mPrefs = CubeWallpaper1.this.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME, 0);
            mPrefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
            onSharedPreferenceChanged(mPrefs, null);
            mStartTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);
            setTouchEventsEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mDrawCube);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
            mVisible = visible;
            if (visible) {
                drawFrame();
            } else {
                mHandler.removeCallbacks(mDrawCube);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            super.onSurfaceChanged(holder, format, width, height);
            screenwidth = width;
            halfscreenwidth = width/2.0f;
            screenheight = height;
            screenhalfheight = height/2.0f;
            drawFrame();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            super.onSurfaceCreated(holder);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            super.onSurfaceDestroyed(holder);
            mVisible = false;
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mDrawCube);
        }

        @Override
        public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset, float yOffset,
                float xStep, float yStep, int xPixels, int yPixels) {
            mOffset = xOffset;
            drawFrame();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                mTouchX = event.getX();
                mTouchY = event.getY();
            } else {
                mTouchX = -1;
                mTouchY = -1;
            }
            super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        void drawFrame() {
            final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();

            Canvas c = null;
            try {
                c = holder.lockCanvas();
                if (c != null) {
                    drawCube(c);
                    drawTouchPoint(c);
                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null) holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }

            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mDrawCube);
            if (mVisible) {


                mHandler.postDelayed(mDrawCube, 1000 / 600);

                if(framerate==slow){
                    Log.v("slow call ","screen height");
                    mHandler.postDelayed(mDrawCube, 1000 / 100);

                }

                else if(framerate==medium){
                    Log.v("medium call ","screen height");
                    mHandler.postDelayed(mDrawCube, 1000 / 400);

                }

                else if(framerate==fast){
                    Log.v("fast call ","screen height");
                    mHandler.postDelayed(mDrawCube, 1000 / 1000);

                }


            }
        }


        void drawCube(Canvas c) {
            c.save();
            c.drawColor(0xff000000);
            if(Reverse)
            {
                if (i>73 || i<1)
                {
                    plus = !plus;
                    if(plus )
                        i+=2;
                    else
                        i-=2;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(i>73)
                    i=1;
                plus =true;
            }
            try {
                if(i<=0 || i>73)
                    i=1;

                THIS IS MY BACKROUND
                Bitmap holdmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getAssets().open( "hold.png"));

                                THIS IS MY IMAGE ANIMATION  
                Bitmap bitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getAssets().open((i/10)+""+(i%10)+".png"));




                int imgh = bitmap.getHeight();
                int himgh = bitmap.getHeight()/2;
                int imgw = bitmap.getWidth();
                int himgw = bitmap.getWidth()/2;



                if(screenfit==false){
                    if(imgw>screenwidth){


                        float w1 = imgw - screenwidth;
                        float omg = imgw-w1;
                        float nw1 = w1/imgw*100;

                        float h1 = imgh - screenheight;
                        float hmg =imgh-h1;
                        float nh1 = h1/imgh*100;        
                        RectF rf = new RectF(0,0,omg,hmg);
                        RectF rf2 = new RectF(0,0,300,300);


                        c.drawBitmap(holdmap, null, rf, mPaint);
                        c.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, rf2, mPaint);




                    }else if (imgw<screenwidth){

                        float w1 = imgw - screenwidth;
                        float omg=imgw-w1;
                        float nw1 = w1/imgw*100;

                        float h1 = imgh - screenheight;
                        float hmg =imgh-h1;
                        float nh1 = h1/imgh*100;        
                        RectF rf = new RectF(0,0,omg,hmg);
                        RectF rf2 = new RectF(0,0,300,300);


                        c.drawBitmap(holdmap, null, rf, mPaint);
                        c.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, rf2, mPaint);

                    }


                }else if (screenfit==true){

                    if(imgw>screenwidth){                       
                        float w1 = imgw - screenwidth;
                        float omg=imgw-w1;
                        float nw1 = w1/imgw*100;

                        float h1 = imgh - screenheight;
                        float hmg =imgh-h1;
                        float nh1 = h1/imgh*100;        
                        RectF rf = new RectF(0,0,omg,hmg);
                        RectF rf2 = new RectF(0,0,300,300);


                        c.drawBitmap(holdmap, null, rf, mPaint);
                        c.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, rf2, mPaint);


                    }else if (imgw<screenwidth){
                        float w1 = imgw - screenwidth;
                        float omg=imgw-w1;
                        float nw1 = w1/imgw*100;

                        float h1 = imgh - screenheight;
                        float hmg =imgh-h1;
                        float nh1 = h1/imgh*100;        
                        RectF rf = new RectF(0,0,omg,hmg);
                        RectF rf2 = new RectF(0,0,300,300);


                        c.drawBitmap(holdmap, null, rf, mPaint);
                        c.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, rf2, mPaint);
                    }
                }

                if(plus )
                    i++;
                else
                    i--;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            c.restore();

        }









        void drawTouchPoint(Canvas c) {
            if (mTouchX >=0 && mTouchY >= 0) {
                c.drawCircle(mTouchX, mTouchY, 0, mPaint);
            }
        }

        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
            Reverse = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("reverse", false);
            screenfit = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("screenfit", false);
            framerate = sharedPreferences.getString("framerate","fast");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: have you see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143321/how-to-align-center-a-bitmap

Comment: Yes, but it didn't help at all